# Recording conversation with cordova-plugin-media

Tags: android, cordova, record, phonegap, recording

I'm using cordova-plugin-media for develop an Android App for recording conversation, but it record only my voice from mic.

Is this plugin appropriate for develop it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cordova-plugin-media plugin is used to record audio from the mic. What kind of conversation would you like to record? Both voices in a telephone call?

Comment: Yes, both mic and voice in a telephone call.